# Removing robots.txt from tomcat

Tags: robots.txt, tomcat9

If I remove robots.txt from my webapps root directory, it's allow the Google bot to crawl pages in my site?

We have already disallowed all th bots, but we want to remove it.
so pls clarify, for bots does missing robots.txt file means don't crawl into the site?

Comment: Removing robots.txt only prevents [well-behaved robots from crawling your website](https://www.robotstxt.org/faq/prevent.html) (Google is well-behaved). There's probably nothing you can do to completely prevent your website from being indexed anywhere. Also it might take a few days for your page to be deleted from Google index of you specified you don't want crawling afterwards.

Comment: @Arthur So disallowing all bots and removing it have the same effect?

Comment: Disallowing is considered better for well-behaved bots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A missing `robots.txt` file, means it's open for unlimited crawling by anyone.

Also, most websites don’t need a robots.txt file.

It is better practice to have an `robots.txt` listing disallowed paths, than rejecting/blocking the HTTP requests based on the User-Agent string.

---

*A little side note:*

*On dynamic web pages, it's relatively easy to filter bots on runtime, using the User-Agent string, but it may be more difficult to rejecting bots on static assets, like files or images.*

*Also, many bots doesn't even have the word `bot` or `crawler` in it's User-Agent string, making it harder to differentiate humans from bots.*